# WPF: Looking for a fast method to display a rgb pixel array (byte) to canvas to create an image

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, byte, pixel

i have an array = byte[512,512] in each field i have an value from 0 to 255 which then represents gray color (from white to black) for each pixel. Until now i cameup with a code which creates a new rectangle (width 1 height 1) for each array field and then puts it on canvas. This method is very slow (at least on my laptop). It usualy takes up to 30 or maybe 40 seconds.

I would be very happy if someone could show me how to do this in some other way.
thank you in advance.

```
private void draw_a_pixel(Rectangle pixel, double top, int widthCounter)
    {
        Canvas.SetTop(pixel, Convert.ToInt32(top));
        Canvas.SetLeft(pixel, widthCounter);
        canvas1.Children.Add(pixel);

    }
```

this is the section of the code that takes the most amount of time i think.

Comment: An array of pixels is called an image..! Have a look at `WriteableBitmap`.

Comment: Yeah, pixel by pixel is just not going to be fast...although 30s seems extreme.

Comment: Hi Chris I already tried with WriteableBitmap but i couldn't find any good examples of how to generate it or display it later on canvas. So i was hoping if you could share some knowledge about this and maybe wrote me a symple sample code that would work in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chris said, you should use the `WriteableBitmap`.

Here is some material to start:

```
/// <summary>
/// method that will create a source for your image object,
/// and fill it with a specified array of pixels
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pixels">your array of pixels</param>
/// <returns>your image object</returns>
public BitmapSource DrawImage(Int32[,] pixels)
{
    int resX = pixels.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
    int resY = pixels.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;

    WriteableBitmap writableImg = new WriteableBitmap(resX, resY, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

    //lock the buffer
    writableImg.Lock();

    for (int i = 0; i < resX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < resY; j++)
        {
            IntPtr backbuffer = writableImg.BackBuffer;
            //the buffer is a monodimensionnal array...
            backbuffer += j * writableImg.BackBufferStride;
            backbuffer += i * 4;
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteInt32(backbuffer, pixels[i,j]);
        }
    }

    //specify the area to update
    writableImg.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, resX, resY));
    //release the buffer and show the image
    writableImg.Unlock();

    return writableImg;
}
```

Each pixel of your array has to be an Int32.
Here is a function to convert RGB color code to Int32

```
/// <summary>
/// Return the specified color code as a Int32
/// </summary>
public Int32 GetColor(byte r, byte g, byte b)
{
    return Int32.Parse(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b).ToString().Trim('#'), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
```

Fill your array of pixels the way you want.

Add a `Image` to your XAML and update the source.

```
<Image x:Name="Chart"/>

Chart.Source = DrawImage(pixels);
```

Comment: Thank you alot. Your explanation was spot on and your code samples work 100%!

Answer (score 1):

You may create a grayscale bitmap from a two dimensional array of bytes with a method like shown below. The pixels array is copied into a pixel buffer that fits the `Gray8` format, i.e. grayscale with 8 bits per pixel.

```
public static BitmapSource GetBitmap(byte[,] pixels)
{
    var width = pixels.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
    var height = pixels.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
    var buffer = new byte[width * height];

    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            buffer[width * y + x] = pixels[x, y];
        }
    }

    var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(
        width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray8, null, buffer, width);
    bitmap.Freeze();

    return bitmap;
}
```

If a byte actually represents a value that ranges from white to black instead of black to white, just write

```
buffer[width * y + x] = (byte)(255 - pixels[x, y]);
```

You may than have an Image control in XAML

```
<Image x:Name="image" />
```

and assign the bitmap to its Source property:

```
image.Source = GetBitmap(pixels);
```

You may also get a more responsive UI if you create the bitmap in a background thread, like

```
image.Source = await Task.Run(() => GetBitmap(pixels));
```